# Applying for 'qualification' for MCF position in France: documents in English

Tags: cv, france

I would like to apply for MCF (Maître de conférences - eqvivalent to assistent professor) position in France. This, however, requires applying for so-called Qualification at the Galaxie portal (https://www.galaxie.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/ensup/CNU_qualification.htm), in my case in section: applied math.

I am wondering: Does anybody here have experience with the portal? Is it possible to upload a CV in English? Or is it necessary to translate everything into French?
Is there any recommendation on what CV should contain for the successful qualification?

I would be glad if anybody would share their experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need your CV translated/already in French, the only exception is for qualifying works

---

Article 5 of the [Arrêté du 11 juillet 2018 relatif à la procédure d'inscription sur les listes de qualification aux fonctions de maître de conférences ou de professeur des universités](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/id/JORFTEXT000037308181/2023-07-12/) states :

> Les diplômes, rapports de soutenance, attestations et justificatifs rédigés en langue étrangère sont accompagnés d'une traduction en langue française dont le candidat atteste la conformité sur l'honneur. A défaut, le dossier sera déclaré irrecevable. [...]

> Translation mine
>
> Dipomas, defense reports, attestations and justifications written in foreign languages are to be accompanied with a French translation the candidate sworns is accurate

---

There is an exception :

> [...] Dès lors que les documents mentionnés au 3° de l'article 4 sont rédigés en langue étrangère, un résumé rédigé en langue française doit être transmis, par l'ensemble des candidats concernés et pour chaque document, si la section le demande.

> When documents from the third point of Article 4 are written in foreign languages, a summary written in French must be sent, for all the candidates in question and for every documents, if the sections demands it

Article 4.3 states :

> 3° Un exemplaire des travaux, ouvrages et articles dans la limite de trois documents pour les candidats à la qualification aux fonctions de maître de conférences et de cinq documents pour les candidats à la qualification aux fonctions de professeur des universités ;

> A copy of works, books and articles, 3 maximum for the candiates to the functions of maître de conférences and 5 for candiates to the function of university professor

Comment: Thanks! Quick question: what do you mean by qualifying works? for qualification?

Comment: Does point 4.3 means that I should provide translated abstracts of my 3 published papers?

Comment: @computational_scientist The qualifying works is point 4.3, for those you are only required to provide a translated abstracts if it you are specifically asked for those...

Comment: Well, there is the law that contains remnants of the world 50 years back, and there is how things really work today... You could email the examiners that are assigned to you and ask if English is fine. I think examiner details are shown in Galaxie. To show your motivation, it would still be good to have at least the CV in French.